# React Component Not Re-rendering with react-test-renderer and react-query

Tags: unit-testing, react-testing-library, react-query, msw, react-test-renderer

I'm facing a peculiar issue while testing my React components. When I use react-test-renderer in conjunction with react-query, my components don't seem to trigger a re-render after receiving data from an API response. This results in the component not displaying the fetched data.

However, when I switch to using @testing-library/react for testing, the components re-render as expected and display the data correctly. I'm using Mock Service Worker (MSW) to mock the API responses, and it seems to work fine with @testing-library/react.

Does anyone know why react-test-renderer might not trigger a re-render with react-query, and how to resolve this issue?

**My component**

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import axios from "axios";

const fetchData = async () => {
  const { data } = await axios.get("https://api.example.com/user");
  console.log("fetchData", data);

  return data;
};

const Example = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["repoData"],
    queryFn: fetchData,
  });

  console.log("re-render", data);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>name: {data?.name}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import Example from "./Example";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { http, HttpResponse } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import { act, create } from "react-test-renderer";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      retry: false,
    },
  },
});

const wrapper = () => (
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <Example />
  </QueryClientProvider>
);

const server = setupServer(
  http.get("https://api.example.com/user", ({ request, params, cookies }) => {
    return HttpResponse.json({
      name: "mocked-react-query",
    });
  })
);

beforeEach(() => {
  server.listen();
});

afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
afterAll(() => server.close());

let tree
test("test react-test-renderer", async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    await create(wrapper());
  });

  await act(async () => {});

  const h1 = await tree.root.findByType("h1");
  expect(h1.props.children[1]).toEqual("mocked-react-query");
});

test("test @testing-library/react", async () => {
  const result = render(wrapper());
  expect(await result.findByText(/mocked-react-query/i)).not.toBeNull();
});
```

**test with @testing-library/react**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7O0b.png)

**test with react-test-renderer**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL0d7.png)

Environment:
React version: 18.2.0
react-query version: 5.9.0
react-test-renderer version: 18.2.0
@testing-library/react version: 5.9.0
MSW version: 2.0.9

I expect that when using react-test-renderer for testing React components with react-query, the components should re-render upon receiving data from an API response